# How to get the XPATH from here?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[Full view of html (view this to understand the page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHcYf.png)Here I want to get the Xpath of `td` that has `pointer` class on `font` and `strong` tag inside also value inside `[5/6]`.

[xpath i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX99h.png)

```html
<tr>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="calendarHoliday">01.05.</font>
    </td>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="pointer" onclick="javascript:showHideDivForModal('submitModalPanel','visible');openUrl('./calendarDay.do?day=02.05.2023&amp;timeSlotId=&amp;calendarId=1453526&amp;consularPostId=567');">
            <strong>02.05.</strong>
            <br>[4/4]
        </font>
    </td>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="pointer" onclick="javascript:showHideDivForModal('submitModalPanel','visible');openUrl('./calendarDay.do?day=03.05.2023&amp;timeSlotId=&amp;calendarId=1453526&amp;consularPostId=567');">
            <strong>03.05.</strong>
            <br>[5/6]
        </font>
    </td>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="pointer" onclick="javascript:showHideDivForModal('submitModalPanel','visible');openUrl('./calendarDay.do?day=04.05.2023&amp;timeSlotId=&amp;calendarId=1453526&amp;consularPostId=567');">
            <strong>04.05.</strong>
            <br>[6/6]
        </font>
    </td>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="calendarHoliday">05.05.</font>
    </td>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="calendarHoliday">06.05.</font>
    </td>
    <td class="calendarMonthCell">
        <font class="calendarHoliday">07.05.</font>
    </td>                   
</tr>
```

Now I am trying to get that element like `//*[@class="pointer"]//strong` but I want to change that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select `td` node that *has `font` child node with `@class="pointer"` AND `strong` ancestor node AND contains text `"[5/6]"`* try

```
//td[font[@class="pointer"] and .//strong and contains(., "[5/6]")]
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed it with something else.